# How to bind to ActualWidth property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, data-binding

I want to align view model items (from a source) in a `ListView` having a `WrapPanel` as ItemsPanel, so that the items are basically aligned in two columns, but if an item is wider than one column, it wraps and thus makes its *row* higher.

I want to achieve this by a `Grid` control having the same width as the `ListView` having two columns, and then get (bind) the width of one item from the `ActualWidth` of one of the `ColumnDefinition`s of the `Grid`.

So, I created the following XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--The column to bind from is a bit less wide than 50% to enable some margin between items in the same row.-->
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="clm1" Width="45*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="55*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="some width" Height="some height" ItemsSource="some source">
        <!--the wrap panel that wraps items after two is in a row-->
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel ItemWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=clm1}" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--some properties are binded to the view model object in the DataContext-->
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <!--separate TextBlock is for text wrapping-->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

However, this does not work, the items are aligned as in a regular WrapPanel, rather than in columns.

The **reason** why this does not work: I checked (in Live Property Explorer) what value the **binding** to `ActualWidth` evaluates to, and it is `double.NaN`, although the `ActualWidth` property has a normal numerical value.

So the main question is: why that **binding** does not work?
(And the secondary question is: how to properly achieve the desired **layout**?)

Comment: Because the WrapPanel is within a Template, the column you are trying to bind to may be out of scope -- meaning, the WrapPanel does not know the element "clm1". One alternative is to bind the actual width of clm1 to a property in the Window/Page's datacontext and then bind the WrapPanel's width to the same property. If the DataContext implements INotifyPropertyChanged and you trigger the property changed notification whenever the Width property is updated, this should work

Comment: @J.D. So would I have to create a new class that has a dependency property for this purpose?

Comment: How are you  providing data to your ListView? Is it by binding to a datasource in a viewmodel? Or are you using codebehind? If you have a view model, you can add the property there (if you view model implements INotifyPropertyChanged).

Comment: @J.D. Oh ok now I got the point. If you posted your suggestion as an answer, I'd accept it. Btw do you consider creating such a property in the view model class an elegant solution? I mean, is this what view model objects are for, actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a view model depends on the desired architecture of your solution. For example, I use the [MSDN MVVM Pattern](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiogeL8_t7VAhVDeSYKHQqaB88QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fhh848246.aspx&usg=AFQjCNGb4OXP5lLoQPJ41Xb8rmtpWVKjvw) for larger projects because it allows for better unit testing. In my humble opinion, when you need to do complex bindings and are working with a lot of data, view models are a more elegant solution.